# Air quality sensor reading meaning

Tags: arduino-uno

So I got this air quality sensor running, and it's outputting some numbers.
I've read some tutorial online and it looks like the smaller the number the better the air quality.
But I don't understand what is the meaning of those number. Like what is the unit of measurement? For example, the temperature sensor gives you numbers in Celcius degree.

http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-Air_Quality_Sensor_v1.3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of those [MQ gas sensors](https://playground.arduino.cc/Main/MQGasSensors) ? They are electrochemical sensors. They can be calibrated more or less with a known concentration of a certain gas. But since the are often sensitive to a number of gasses, you do not know the concentration of that specific gas that was used for calibration.

A number that is going up and down is what you have. You can make a graph with it to show the value for each hour or each day.

The MQ gas sensors have a "preheat" or "burn-in" time. It is often 24 hours. Keep the sensor on for 24 hours to get more stable output values.

A temperature sensor is completely different, it contains electronics inside and has been calibrated at the factory. The MQ gas sensors are just a few wires, a heater and some chemicals.

[**ADDED**]
That is a module with the MP503 gas sensor. It just like the MQ sensors a electrochemical gas sensor. According to the datasheet it is sensitive for alcohol and smoke and the "preheat" or "burn-in" is called "aging time" and can be up to one week! The module has a amplifier.

The detection of gasses is according to a certain curve. To calculate the concentration of gasses a calculation is needed (and a calibrated sensor). I don't see that calculation in the supplied library. So all you have is numbers that change according to the air quality. That's all. And that is normal for these sensors.

Read the information and pdf files on that seeed page about this Grove module. It clearly says that you can't measure the concentration of gas (not "quantitatively"), you can only tell if the air quality gets better or worse (qualitative).

Comment: This actually http://wiki.seeed.cc/Grove-Air_Quality_Sensor_v1.3/

Comment: I have found that they will give false positives immediately upon power-on, so if they are being used for alarms you might want to build a delay into your program to allow it to heat up.   -- The datasheet says it takes 24 hours to reach factory specifications, but you might try giving it a few hours and see if it working well enough for your particular project.  Ambient temperatures are an issue, of course.  The cooler the environment then the longer it will take to become accurate enough.